# setActiveTab in ons-tabbar - need correct sample

Tags: onsen-ui

```
        <ons-page id="page-newHome" on-device-backbutton="askExit()" sliding-menu-ignore="true">
            <ons-tabbar var="homeTab">
                <ons-tabbar-item page="page0.html" label="TAB0" icon="search" active="true"></ons-tabbar-item>
                <ons-tabbar-item page="page1.html" label="TAB1" icon="heart-o"></ons-tabbar-item>
                <ons-tabbar-item page="page2.html" label="TAB2" icon="comment-o"></ons-tabbar-item>
                <ons-tabbar-item page="page3.html" label="TAB3" icon="user-o"></ons-tabbar-item>
            </ons-tabbar>
        </ons-page>
```

When I call homeTab.setActiveTab(3) Why it said Uncaught ReferenceError: homeTab is not defined

Comment: `var="homeTab"` is not creating any variable. `var` is only available with AngularJS bindings. Are you using AngularJS?

Comment: <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script> 
Yes I'm using angularjs

Comment: Actually I never get right on setActiveTab & getActiveTabIndex(), this method seems not available for me. I wonder what case may blocking these?

Comment: If you are using Onsen UI 2 you also need to include `<script src="lib/onsen/js/angular-onsenui.js"></script>`

Comment: Solve by changing ons-tabbar-item into ons-tab

Comment: Where did you find `ons-tabbar-item` syntax?

Comment: From this => http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/FqJjt